# PgBouncer on separate server than PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

Right now I am hosting PostgreSQLand PgBouncer on the same Linode with 48GB of RAM and 12 Cores.

The server gets many short lived connections per second. The server load will increase with time and I want to reduce the server load as much as possible.

When I look at the 'top' command on the server, I see that PgBouncer is taking about 30% CPU usage. Would I benefit by creating another Linode and running PgBouncer on that server by itself?

Answer (score 1):

The `top` command gives the CPU usage per core. Since you have 12 I would not create another Linode for that. Check the line with `Cpu(s)`. There you will find the `%id` which is a better indication weather or not your server is using it's full CPU capacity.

Answer (score 1):

***If possible***, rather than creating a new Linode(thanks for enlightening me), if you are able to create pgbouncer on the source (webserver or whatever) of the short lived connections, then you'll also save on the network time to make the connection.

Comment: Can you point me to something I can read about this? I want to set this up